# Conectar MySQL con Node.js

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Buen día, tengo una API Rest que me conecta sin problemas con MongoDB, pero quiero que me conecte con MySQL, pero no he podido quitar MongoDB para colocar MySQL, he hecho varios intentos, pero no me conecta con MySQL.

##### Original con MongoDB:

**config.js**

```javascript
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dbConnection = async() => {

    try {

        await mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGODB_CNN, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        });
    
        console.log('Base de datos online');

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error a la hora de iniciar la base de datos');
    }

}

module.exports = {
    dbConnection
}
```

**.env**

```
PORT=8080
MONGODB_CNN=mongodb+srv://cafe_user:YkHaHZTN1mGqKLLO@cafecluster.7fet5.mongodb.net/CafeDB
SECRETORPRIVATEKEY=EsTaEsmiPalabr@secretaDeTokENS123321
CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://776571654463621:2U14cGjxKWwFrA4GA6wQYNjW_H4@dwragjgy0
```

##### Ahora MySQL: (La parte que no me funciona)

**config.js**

```javascript
const mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();

const dbConnection = async() => {

    try {

        await mysql.connect( process.env, {
            host: 'process.env.DBHOST',
            user: 'process.env.DBUSER',
            password: 'process.env.DBPASSWORD',
            database: 'process.env.DATABASE'
        });
        
        console.log('Base de datos online');

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error a la hora de iniciar la base de datos');
    }


}

module.exports = {
    dbConnection
}
```

**.env**

```
PORT=8080
DBHOST: localhost
DBUSER: node_user2
DBPASSWORD: 123456
DATABASE: node_db
```

---

### Actualización

Agrego también el `server.js`, donde muestro las otras configuraciones que hay, ya que al modificar `config.js` para MySQL también arroja errores en consola de este archivo.
He intentado varias opciones, pero ninguna me funciona, solo trabaja con MongoDB.

**server.js**

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const { dbConnection } = require('../database/config');

class Server {

    constructor() {
        this.app  = express();
        this.port = process.env.PORT;

        this.paths = {
            auth:       '/api/auth',
            buscar:     '/api/buscar',
            categorias: '/api/categorias',
            productos:  '/api/productos',
            usuarios:   '/api/usuarios',
            uploads:    '/api/uploads',
        }


        // Conectar a base de datos
        this.conectarDB();

        // Middlewares
        this.middlewares();

        // Rutas de mi aplicación
        this.routes();
    }

    async conectarDB() {
        await dbConnection();
    }


    middlewares() {

        // CORS
        this.app.use( cors() );

        // Lectura y parseo del body
        this.app.use( express.json() );

        // Directorio Público
        this.app.use( express.static('public') );

        // Fileupload - Carga de archivos
        this.app.use( fileUpload({
            useTempFiles : true,
            tempFileDir : '/tmp/',
            createParentPath: true
        }));

    }

    routes() {
        
        this.app.use( this.paths.auth, require('../routes/auth'));
        this.app.use( this.paths.buscar, require('../routes/buscar'));
        this.app.use( this.paths.categorias, require('../routes/categorias'));
        this.app.use( this.paths.productos, require('../routes/productos'));
        this.app.use( this.paths.usuarios, require('../routes/usuarios'));
        this.app.use( this.paths.uploads, require('../routes/uploads'));
        
    }

    listen() {
        this.app.listen( this.port, () => {
            console.log('Servidor corriendo en puerto', this.port );
        });
    }

}

module.exports = Server;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de tus problemas reside en que en el `.env` del MySQL tienes `:` en vez de `=`

Pásalo a lo siguiente:

```
PORT=8080
DBHOST=localhost
DBUSER=node_user2
DBPASSWORD=123456
DATABASE=node_db
```

Otro problema es que solamente has cogido código que funciona con un módulo de MongoDB y le has cambiado las partes que pone MongoDB por MySQL y crees que eso va a funcionar... Son módulos completamente diferentes y nada tienen que ver el uno con el otro, no puedes esperar que cambiando 4 nombres funcione como si nada...

Cambia el `config.js` a lo siguiente:

```javascript
var mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();

const dbConnection = async() => {
    var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DBHOST,
        user: process.env.DBUSER,
        password: process.env.DBPASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
 
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

    });

    return connection;
}
```

**Tendrás que recoger el return en donde llamas a la función del 'server.js'**, esto pasa porque necesitas el `connecion` que estás declarando para realizar las querys.

Te dejo la documentación del [paquete MySQL de node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction) para que le eches un ojo

Comment: ya agregue el cambio pero sigue con el mismo problema no conecta con mysql

Comment: @Giovanny De acuerdo, perdona. Error mío te edito la respuesta y añado más porque se me ha pasado una cosa

Comment: @Giovanny ya lo tienes

Comment: agregue el codigo que me envio pero ahora me muestra un error en consola del archivo server.js line 34
        "await dbConnection();"
, donde dice "TypeError: dbConnection is not a function"  . subi a la pregunta el archivo server.js ya que al adicionar tu respuesta ocasiona este error.

Comment: Le has quitado el `module.exports = { dbConnection }` al archivo `config.js` no?

Comment: Si lo has quitado, nose yo si te funcionara, porque tu lo estas ejecutando como si fuera una funcion con `async conectarDB() { await dbConnection(); }` en el archivo `server.js`....

Comment: module.exports = { dbConnection } esta agregado al final del config.js pero en consola me sigue apareciendo el error que te menciono.

Comment: @Giovanny lo edito de nuevo

Comment: @Giovanny Varias cosas... 1) En vez de coger un código que funciona con unos módulos específicos y cambiar unos nombres para que se amolde a lo que quieres, pero con módulos diferentes (Lo cual no funciona) rehaz la aplicación o los scripts o lo que sea. 2) Leete por favor [Formato de preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) para que aprendas a añadir preguntas con buen formato... Te he editado la pregunta dos veces para corregir formatos y sigues añadiéndolo mal sin ni siquiera mirar...